# Doublicating instantiated objects with instanciated_object( i )?

Tags: python, methods

I am in the process of learning python and I am trying to understand a pacman program by working through the code. So far its going well (and thanks to the StackOverflow Community who at times has been really helpful).

I ran into a snag, when looking at the following instantiation methods:

**Here is the code I have difficulties with:**

```
ghostType = loadAgent(options.ghost, noKeyboard) ## This line uses the loadAgent function below to load the agents operating the ghost specified by the user through the command line. There are different types of ghosts. One the user specified a ghost agent they want to use all ghost-agents will use the same ghost agent type.
args['ghosts'] = [ghostType( i+1 ) for i in range( options.numGhosts )]
```

**The variables in the code are:**

- options.ghost #Type of agent automatically operating the ghosts.
  These are specified by a user prior to starting a game via the
  command line. Different kind of ghost agents make the ghosts behave
  differently. But once a ghost type has been chosen, all ghosts in the
  game will use the same agent type.
- options.numGhosts #Number of ghosts in the game. This is also
  specified by the user via the command line prior to starting a game.

**MY QUESTION:**

***I am confused by the ghostType(i+1) expression.***

I know each game has several ghosts that are operated automatically by ghost agents.

1. It seems like adding (i+1) to the ghostType variable creates more of the same variables.
   Is that correct?
2. Is that something that can be applied as a general rule? Meaning, if I instantiated an object into a variable, can I save several version of this instantiated object in a dictionary by following this pattern?

Pattern?

> variable = method_that_instantiates_an_object
>
> dict['key'] = [variable(i+1) for i in range(list)]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Mike

**To provide you with a complete picture of what is going on:**

Each ghost agent is initialised via the loadAgent method specified below:

```
def loadAgent(pacman, nographics):                   
    pythonPathStr = os.path.expandvars("$PYTHONPATH") # Looks through all pythonPath Directories for the right module.
    if pythonPathStr.find(';') == -1:                 ## This 'find' method returns the index position where the seach term was found whithin the string and '-1' if it couldn't be found.
        pythonPathDirs = pythonPathStr.split(':')    
        
    else:
        pythonPathDirs = pythonPathStr.split(';')
    pythonPathDirs.append('.')

    for moduleDir in pythonPathDirs:
        if not os.path.isdir(moduleDir): continue     ## the os.path.isdir(path) method returns TRUE if path is an existing directory.
        moduleNames = [f for f in os.listdir(moduleDir) if f.endswith('gents.py')] ##this line basically finds all the module's whose names end with 'gents.py' and loads them into a list called moduleNames.
        print(moduleNames)
        for modulename in moduleNames:
            try:
                module = __import__(modulename[:-3]) ## X = __import__(‘X’) works like import X, with the difference that you A -pass the module name as a string, and B - explicitly assign it to a variable in your current namespace ### This is a way of importing a module when you don't have the module name yet.
            except ImportError:                      
                continue
            if pacman in dir(module):                ## This line checks whether the variable 'pacman' which was passed to the loadAgent function is part of the 'module' module wich was just imported. For example the agent LeftTurnAgent is specified in the pacmanAgents.py module. The 'pacman' variable contains which agent type the program is supposed to use. If this type is part of the 'module'-module the function returns the agent and the module-code in the 'module' viariable. 
               if nographics and modulename == 'keyboardAgents.py': ## This line checks whether the 'nographics variable' was activated by the user in the command line function. Nongraphics is an option the developers of this code introduced to be able to run and analyse 100ds of games at the same time. If that was the case, the user can't be the agent operating the game and the game will raise an exception.
                  raise Exception('Using the keyboard requires graphics (not text display)')
              return getattr(module, pacman)       ## getattr(module, pacman) is equivalent to module.pacman. This is a way of referencing a function without knowing its name until run-time.For example, if we call the LeftTurnAgent this would be a call to the pacmanAgents.LeftTurnAgent.
     raise Exception('The agent ' + pacman + ' is not specified in any *Agents.py.')
```